# Windows 8 force battery/plugged-in icon to show in task bar

Tags: windows-8, laptop, battery, taskbar

On laptop systems with a battery, Windows 8 shows either a battery icon (when running from battery) or a "plugged in" icon (when running from AC).

Clicking on this icon allows changing the power schemes very quickly.

On systems without a battery this symbol is missing, making it awkward to change power schemes often.

On Windows XP one could select an option "always show battery icon" (named similarly) that would force the display of the "plugged in" symbol even on system without a battery.

Does a similar option (or Registry Key) exist on Windows 8?

Comment: Could this possibly help you [Cant see battery icon windows 8](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/i-cant-see-battery-icon-windows-8/acc98591-626d-4081-b654-781a012c912c)

Comment: @NetworkKingPin That describes how to unhide any taskbar icon. In my case the icon is not hidden. It does not exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://en.bmode.tarcode.ru/) third-party utility which works like standard battery icon, even on non-laptop systems.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv2Nb.png)